# An elegant way to cast string to number in a Typescript class w/o using a constructor?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have to read JSON responses where all the parameters are encoded as strings, regardless of whether they're numeric. I want to strict type these into various Typescript classes. So let's say the JSON is like this:

```
{"id":"1","label":"Alice"}
```

And I have a Typescript class like this:

```
class Person {
    public id:number;
    public label:string;
}
```

In a language like AS3, let's say, I could avoid having an explicit constructor and just say:

```
var p:Person = new Person();
p.id=jsonInput.id;
p.label=jsonInput.label;
```

And the id would then be automatically typed to a number. No parseInt() or parseFloat() or *1 necessary.

In my case I have to quickly loop through a variety of large, complex JSON objects of this sort which need to regularly create, update and destroy Typescript objects based on server values. I'd like to avoid having to check whether certain parameters are numeric. I've already declared them to be numeric in the class properties I'm putting them into. But what happens is that although Person.id is declared as a number in the Typescript class definition, you can still assign it a string at runtime and it simply acts like a string from that point on.

This is particularly annoying with booleans where the server result is a "0" or "1" string since you can't cast it to a boolean or a number automatically, and every check on those variables later on has to compare them to the string "0" or "1".

So what I'm wondering is, is there an elegant way to handle assignments to class properties so as to force the type I've specified in the class definition onto the input? I mean, rather than check whether something is numeric for every bit of information I receive from the server, I want to leverage the class definition and get either null or an error in that property if I try to assign a non-numeric string to a number; get a string if I assign a numeric value to a variable typed as "string"; get a boolean if I assign anything other than 0 or false to a variable typed as "boolean"... etc. Like in other languages. Is that possible?

Comment: Typescript is a compile time only type system. There simply are no types at runtime anymore.

Comment: I realize that... still, I'm wondering if there are other solutions people have come up with... maybe something involving watching the object (prototype.watch() is deprecated, I know) and automatically type-checking and casting whenever it's changed...?

Comment: @joshstrike The only reason AS3 could do this is because types were annotated at runtime, so assignment of a value at runtime could be coerced to the annotated type. JavaScript doesn't have this, so it's not possible. Additionally the type annotations are not readable at runtime (ie there's no type reflection). So yeah, it's a big pain compared to AS3. You can come up with some solutions but they will never be as straight-forward as the AS3 example you gave.

Comment: You could also look into using something like https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts

Comment: Interesting project. I started wondering if there might be a compiler tweak that could do something closer to true type reflections... combining with getter/setters, create a shadow value or some metadata for each declared property at compile time, and use that to run typeOf / instanceOf checks. After looking around more, I have a sense decorators and the reflection polyfill might be the way to go. Not sure how well maintained that project is...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at getter/setter functions.

This would allow you to have additional logic to check/cast the variable into the type you want.

```js
class Person {
  private _id: string

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(val) {
    // do checking to make the id into a string
    this._id = // properValue
  }

}
```

This means that if you have a number and set it to the id you could make the number into a string before it is assigned.

e.g.

Using the following `Person` definition

```js
class Person {
  private _id: string

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(val) {
    // example handling of both number and string value
    this._id = typeof val === 'number' ? `${val}` : val
  }

}
```

You can assign numbers to the `id` attribute and they will be converted to strings.

```js
const myPerson: Person = new Person();
myPerson.id = 2
typeof myPerson.id // string
```